# Transferring files over local IP instead of URL

Tags: networking, dns, nextcloud

I have a nextcloud server running on my local network. Unfortunately due to Comcast's data caps, I would like to transfer files to the site locally. If I have another computer on my network and I go to 192.168.1.x (server's local address), would the file transfer be internal?

Right now if I go to 192.168.1.x, the server redirects to example.com (my url). Does this mean that a file transfer currently would be external and count on my data cap?

My solution would be to create a DNS (my DNS server is not local) record like: internal.example.com and point it to 192.168.1.x would this work?

Answer (score 0):

If you get redirected to example.com then yes you are using the external network and it will count on your data cap.

I assume that you want your devices to automatically connect to the internal IP address when on the local network, and connect to the external address when on an external network.

What you could do is to leave your DNS settings as is and install something like DNSMasq on a local server (e.g. your Nextcloud server). Then you'll have to setup this server as an extra DNS server for your devices.

More information:
 - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dnsmasq
 - https://serverfault.com/questions/136332/setting-up-dnsmasq-for-a-local-network
 - https://serverfault.com/questions/608507/dns-a-record-pointing-to-private-ip-address
 - http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html